# heredoc not indenting or working as it should

Tags: php, heredoc

new to PHP. Just having some frustrating problems with heredoc, despite following the book to the letter on syntax. The below text isn't indented as it should be.

```
<?php

$text="Mike's";

echo <<<_END

<!--END is just like double quoteing a var..
You can use single/double quotes without having to escape them first; inside 
END. The last _END tag, has to be on the start of new line with nothing allowed
to procede it, not even whitespace-->

This is the $text 'first line'.

This is the $text 'second line'.

This is the $text 'third line'.
_END;
?>
```

Comment: and what did you expect? Not this? http://codepad.org/kp7Ba18a

Comment: What as the book suggests? If you want an answer you have to ask an actual question. Right now you are just stating that "it doesnt work" but you dont tell how it doesnt work or rather what you expect it to output. The output at the linked codepad is pretty much how it should look like. How do you think it should be indented and what do you get?

Comment: Your example showed how i expected it to look yes, yet it didn't indent (that code should do slightly that's my fault in poorly explaining) nor preserve the whitespace. It actually shows everything on two lines.

Comment: you are likely looking at the output in a browser then. The answer by AD7six is correct in that case. PHP is working as expected here. It's the browser that makes it appear different.

Comment: *(reference)* http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1

Answer (score 2):

Based on the presence of "<!--" - you are creating a html page.

You're looking at the wrong problem, heredocs don't modify whitespace - but html ignores it unless you specify otherwise. To confirm just look at the page source, it'll be what you are expecting.

If you want whitespace to be preserved - use a <pre> tag or more correctly use real markup

i.e.

```
<pre>
This
is
3 lines
<pre>
```

or

```
This<br>
is<br>
3 lines<br>
```

or

```
<p>This<p>
<p>is</p>
<p>3 line</p>
```

will all render on 3 lines.

[w3 whitespace reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1)

Comment: Yes, I knew that thanks. The comments were for me as a reminder over the rules. The book says, the END tag would treat it all as double quotes, preserving, whitespace, indentation and line breaks, so I thought the fact it treated as HTMl was irrelevant due to those tags.